# Best way to communicate between unconnected React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project that has ComponentB nested 5 levels deep inside ComponentA. I want to send information from ComponentB to ComponentA, have it perform some action, then return a new value back to ComponentB. What is the best approach to something like this? I'm still new to React so right now my only understanding is callback functions as props but then I would have to send that function to each component between the ones I care about. Is this where I should use "useContext" or is that for something else?

Comment: Do you know redux? You can examine it.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.javascriptstuff.com/component-communication/, too.